# Where is the best place to put a GET Request, and calling an init function in the the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, get, alamofire

So currently, I'm facing some issues in regards to writing a GET request in my Data Model and calling it in my `ViewController`. I have no issues with writing a GET request and calling it from the `ViewController` if there is no `Init()` function.

You simply initialize the `ViewController` like so and call it in `viewDidLoad`

```
Class ViewController {
  var dataModel = DataModel()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  dataModel.downloadInfo {
     print(dataModel.info)
  // Calls a completion handler, and won't print any info until the data is downloaded. 
  // retrieve the info from the data model. 
   }
}
```

But if in my DataModel I do something like

```
 Class DataModel {
 var info1: String!
 var info2: String!
 var info3: String!

 init(info1: String, info2: String, info3: String) {

}

func downloadInfo(completed: @escaping downloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON { response in
// GET request, parse data, and assign to variables
completed()
   }
  }
  }
```

I can no longer initialize my `ViewController` without passing in these properties. But I can't call these properties until I download the data.

So I can longer do

```
Class ViewController {
  var dataModel = DataModel()
}
```

but if I do

```
Class ViewController {
  var dataModel: DataModel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  dataModel.downloadInfo {
  DataModel(dataModel.info1, dataModel.info2, dataModel.info3)(
 // initialize after properties get downloaded. 
}
```

I get unexpectedly returned nil because I didn't initialize in the beginning.

So I tried initializing with empty data because I can't get retrieve my real data until it gets downloaded.

```
Class ViewController {
 var infoArray = [datModel]()
 var dataModel = DataModel(info1: "", info2: "", info3: "")
 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 dataModel.downloadInfo {
 let infoVar = DataModel(dataModel.info1, dataModel.info2, dataModel.info3)
self.infoArray.append(infoVar)
 //  append the datModel information into an array. 
 }
}
```

Technically this works, but am I doing it wrong, because this seems like a workaround, not a solution to very common task. 
Lastly, the only other problem I receive is that I only get one object in the array, not the hundreds that there should be.

Comment: Having `downloadInfo` as an instance method on your data model doesn't really make sense.  It should be a method in a separate class that is responsible for downloading and creating your model objects or at least it should be a class method if you want to keep it on your data model.

Comment: @dan I just updated my Get Request method to accurately reflect what I have.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach I would go for; is to make the properties **optionals**. It will alleviate you for having to do the work-around you have identified.

```
Class DataModel {
 var info1: String?
 var info2: String?
 var info3: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And secondly, do make the download call async (with a callback as argument to the method) to allow the UI to load immediately. It will make the User experience a lot better!